# How to clear interval outside its closure function or promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, closures, setinterval, clearinterval

How should use `clearInterval()` when I get the response I want inside the second call.

```
axios.post(url1,data1).then(res=>{
    let INTERVAL_ID = setInterval(()=>{myFunc(INTERVAL_ID)},1000)
})

let myFunc = (INTERVAL_ID) => {
    axios.get(url2,data2).then(res=>{
        if (res.data=='abc') clearInterval(INTERVAL_ID) // not clearing interval
    })
}
```

What I want to do is to keep making call until I get the response I want and then terminate interval from the first promise.

Comment: based on the fact that `if (res='abc')` is always true, the issue is most likely that `axios.get(url2,data2)` rejects - I would recommend adding some debugging console.log's and also to `.catch` any rejections to see exactly what is happening

Comment: @JaromandaX it makes the call until get the response it wants. then clears interval.

Comment: I understand what you think it does, but `if (res='abc')` is ALWAYS true - and your code will clear interval, unless `axios.get(url2,data2)` rejects (then won't run in this case - which is why I suggested adding some console.log's and some `.catch`

Comment: how come?! it is not.

Comment: `if (res='abc')` is like doing `res='abc'; if (res)` ... now `'abc'` is truthy, so ... did you want to do `if (res == 'abc')` perhaps? not that this would fix your issue if `axios.get(url2,data2)` never resolves

Comment: it was a typo i fixed. `==` was missing.

Comment: well, now the code looks better ... try adding a `.catch` to the second axios

Comment: why do you need catch to answer this question?

Comment: I don't need .catch ... but, the code as is will now keep calling `myFunc` until `res.data == 'abc'` - so ... how do you know if that condition is ever met? that's why I suggested a long time ago to add some debugging console.logs and maybe a .catch to see if the request is rejecting instead of resolving

Comment: the answer to this question is as follows .... your code will work as you want it to as long as at some point `axios.get(url2,data2)` succeeds AND `res.data == 'abc'` - if this never happens, then the interval will never stop

Comment: .catch was just a *debugging* suggestion ... if that call always succeeds, then the only problem could be that `axios.get(url2,data2)` never returns `abc` in `res.data` - perhaps, instead of asking why I suggest things, just put `console.log(res.data)` just before `if (res.data == 'abc')` to see what `res.data` actually is, to see if it actually ever is `abc` - if not, then you've found why the interval never stops, and you'll need to check the server side to see why it never responds with `abc`

Comment: check the browser developer tools console - any errors?

Comment: `nothing have to do with catch dude` - imagine that `axios.get(url2,data2)` fails (404 error or some such) ... then a `.catch` (for debugging purposes) would show you that - though, if you're looking in the browser developer console, I guess you'd already see that it is failing - you are trying to debug this issue using the browser developer console, right?

Comment: to re-iterate ... my suggestion of `.catch` (and `console.log`) was for determining the cause of *your problem* - I wasn't suggesting you need to include `.catch` in your "production" code (though, really you SHOULD handle errors gracefully) or keep `console.log` in "production" - these were debugging suggestions. Since your code as (now) written SHOULD clear the interval when the right conditions are met, then only reason the interval isn't cleared is that the right conditions are never met - I apologise for attempting to help in a way that you don't understand

Comment: Don't use `setInterval()`. Instead make `myFunc()` recursive. Until the condition is met, call `myFunc()` from a `setTimeout()` inside the `then()` handler. Timing will differ slightly from your `setInterval()` approach, but will guarantee non-overlap of `axios.get()` calls. Also be sure to catch `axios.get()` errors and take appropriate action (continue recursion/log error/whatever). You might choose to introduce an error counter and  recurse until N errors have occurred.